# How to query microsoft academic graph for citation and co-citation?

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-services

Reading through:

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Academic-Knowledge-API/documentation/GraphSearchMethod

It is a bit obscure the meaning of "path":
"path": "/paper/AuthorIDs/author" - I don't see authorIds object in the returned results.

```
# post data query
{
  "path": "/paper/AuthorIDs/author",
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "NormalizedTitle": "graph engine",
    "select": [
      "OriginalTitle"
    ]
  },
  "author": {
    "return": {
      "type": "Author",
      "Name": "bin shao"
    }
  }
}

#results
{
  "Results": [
    [
      {
        "CellID": 2160459668,
        "OriginalTitle": "Trinity: a distributed graph engine on a memory cloud"
      },
      {
        "CellID": 2093502026
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "CellID": 2171539317,
        "OriginalTitle": "A distributed graph engine for web scale RDF data"
      },
      {
        "CellID": 2093502026
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "CellID": 2411554868,
        "OriginalTitle": "A distributed graph engine for web scale RDF data"
      },
      {
        "CellID": 2093502026
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "CellID": 73304046,
        "OriginalTitle": "The Trinity graph engine"
      },
      {
        "CellID": 2093502026
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Which is the correct path (or data to post) to query for citation and co-citation of an article, and paginate results?

Answer (score 3):

You will find `AuthorIDs` on the [graph schema from Microsoft Academic Search](https://www.graphengine.io/docs/apis/mag.html):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the ID of the source paper (2118322263 in the following example), here is the POST part of the request:

```
{
  "path": "/paper/CitationIDs/citation",
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "id": [ 2118322263 ],
    "select": [
      "OriginalTitle"
    ]
  },
  "citation": {
    "return": {
      "type": "Paper"
    },
    "select": [
      "OriginalTitle"
    ]
  }
}
```

This returns 634 results in one response, while a query to the paper itself shows a citation count of 732. I have no idea why there is a difference, nor how to do pagination.